# Why Crypto++ SecByteBlock subscripting works

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, crypto++

I'm trying to understand why following code using Crypto++ SecByteBlock works:

```
SecByteBlock block(10);
std::cout << block[3];
```

It's like `SecByteBlock` has an subscript (`operator[]`) but I can't find it (version 8.2.0, but not present in older versions too). I'm compiling with C++14. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That type has a [conversion](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_sec_block.html#ab7b3f34a0d3670f8f1358bbd72c74716) to (const) `byte *`, which is then used as a basis for indexing.

Comment: How come subscripting triggers this automatically? I don't believe that's a thing.

Comment: Huh, [TIL](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42ac4bc412d35d9a)!

Comment: Ok, then this is unexpected C++ feature for me. Can anybody provide reference where this is described? :)

Comment: commenting out the operator gives a telling error message from visual studio `binary '[': 'A' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`, might give some keywords to search for in the standard

Comment: I can't find the wording in the standard for this, and I'm genuinely surprised that it works. I thought that for class types none of the "built-in" operator rules applied, least of all with attempted conversion of operands. At best we could see this as `*(block+0)` but since when did `op+` convert the LHS to a pointer implicitly? Particularly since `SecByteBlock` has an overloaded op+ so the built-in one shouldn't be invoked anyway.

Comment: The + operator requires another `SecByteBlock` as argument though.

Comment: Exactly, so it's performing conversions to make the built-in `[]` (or the built-in `+`) work. Had no idea would do this. I'm tempted to form a separate language-lawyer-framed question for this.

Comment: I think the key bit is "One of the expressions shall be a glvalue of type “array of T” or a prvalue of type “pointer to T” and the other shall be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral type." [expr.sub] 10 is clearly integral, so the conversion to `byte*` is chosen [over.ics.user] as it is the only (and thus best) choice [over.match.best], I think. Do tag me in the question, I'm curious!

Comment: If operator returns array/pointer then subscript should also work (on that array/pointer): http://cpp.sh/7ncgn.

Comment: block[3] fails to match subscript operator because it doesn't exist. Then it falls back to conversion which gives pointer and then subscripting suddenly works lol.